# HDMI on Raspberry Pi 4b on Ubuntu 19.10.1

Tags: sound, hdmi, display-resolution

I've just installed 19.10.1 on my 4GB Raspberry Pi 4b. My single HDMI display is the wrong resolution and it doesn't fill the entire screen. I am also not getting HDMI sound. I don't have /boot/config.txt or /boot/cmdline.txt. I've tried creating/boot/cmdline.txt and adding HDMI initialization commands to it - without results. I want 1920x2048 at 60Hz.

Answer (score -1):

I just needed to edit `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`.

Here are the lines I placed in `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`.

```
dtparam=audio=on
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
disable_overscan=1
```